# OnPropertyChange does not update combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I feel like I do miss something but I am out of ideas what might be wrong with my code.

I do have a WPF MVVM application with ListView and ComboBox. 
ListBox displays Objects containing two objects, let's say I have a ListBox:

```
Intel <> CPU 
Intel <> GPU
AMD <> CPU
```

and ComboBox with:

```
Intel
AMD
```

What I would like to achieve: 
When I click on the `Intel <> CPU` or `Intel <> GPU` I would like the ComboBox to be set to `Intel`.

My code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPart, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Producers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProducer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Currently when I click on the ListBox item it does fire OnPropertyChanged and enter my method

```
private Parts _selectedPart;
public Parts SelectedPart
{
    get{return _selectedPart;}
    set{
        _selectedPart= value;
        SelectedProducer = _selectedPart.Producer;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRealisation");
    }
}

private Producers _selectedProducer;
public  Producers SelectedProducer 
{
    get{return _selectedProducer; }
    set
    {  _selectedProducer= value;

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProducers");
    }
}
```

It does set the SelectedProducer properly(checked with debugger) it fires `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProducers")` but it doesn't update the ComboBox visible selected value to currently selected value from the ListBox.

Comment: Are the producers in the `Parts` the same objects as in `Producers`? You pass some wrong parameters to `OnPropertyChanged`. For `SelectedProducer` there is an additional s in the parameter string. Furthermore, consider binding the combobox to `SelectedPart.Producer`. This is probably easier to handle and more intuitive.

Comment: It was a mistake, because in real situation I don't have Parts and Producers but I wanted to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

SirKometa,

From your ViewModel it appears that you are not firing the correct `OnPropertyChanged` names try changing the names in the `OnPropertyChanged()` methods to the actual names of the Property (unless there is more of the model missing).

```
private Parts _selectedPart;
public Parts SelectedPart
{
    get{return _selectedPart;}
    set{
        _selectedPart= value;
        SelectedProducer = _selectedPart.Producer;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPart");
    }
}

private Producers _selectedProducer;
public  Producers SelectedProducer 
{
    get{return _selectedProducer; }
    set
    {  _selectedProducer= value;

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProducer");
    }
}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged` should reference the name of the property that has changed. It appears that you have the names incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I dind't really dig deep enough because the answer for my troubles has been on StackOverFlow... I have found it here:
[WPF - MVVM - ComboBox SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062297/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selecteditem?rq=1)

`Producers` has been always retrieving data from the DB and that was the reason why the ComboBox couldn't update.